# Как поставить таймер на кнопку в java?

Tags: java, android, время

Есть код, который выводит сообщение после нажатия кнопки, необходимо после этого нажатия скрывать кнопку и на ее месте запускать таймер на 24 часа, после чего кнопка опять появляется.

Может кто подскажет материалы как это реализовать? Гугл не помог мне!

Мне не понятно - работа с этим таймером. Как его поставить и потом возвращать кнопку? Как при скрытии кнопки отображать на ее месте таймер и затем скрывать таймер?

Сейчас есть код который выводит при нажатии сообщение и затем скрывает кнопку.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String product = "";

            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Guru ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                product = cursor.getString(1);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();

            textView.setText(product);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, для задач по расписанию [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).

В вашем случае, вероятно:

1. При клике в shared preferences вписывать время нажатия.
2. Стартовать таймер с помощью [`Timer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) и [`TimerTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask) или [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), пускай каждую минуту срабатывает.
3. При запуске приложения/пересоздании `Activity` пересоздавать таймер.
4. В обработчике таймера смотреть, если время текущее минус время из `shared preferences` меньше 24 часов, то отображать таймер с временем оставшимся, иначе убирать таймер.

Comment: А можно пример кода?\